# Master-detail page button page color

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, master-pages, master-detail

[image: which is in red]I want to change the color of the button page which is in the master-detail page using Xamarin .forms I use BarTextColor but it didn't work .
Any help please !!

this is the code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="VecottApp.Pages.MDetailPage"
              xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:VecottApp.Pages"
             NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False">
    <MasterDetailPage.Master >

        <pages:MDetailPageMaster x:Name="MasterPage"    />
    </MasterDetailPage.Master>
  <MasterDetailPage.Detail>
        <NavigationPage
      BarBackgroundColor="#3b5998" BarTextColor="Red" >
            <x:Arguments>
                <pages:ProfilePage  />
      </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>
  </MasterDetailPage.Detail>
</MasterDetailPage>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to use a Icon ?

```
<MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Yourproject"
                  x:Class="Yourproject.MainPage"
                  Icon="XXXXXXXXX.png"
                  Title="menu">
```

You can use a word or a symbol that looks like the hamburger menu and put it in Title, because its a easy way to change. The title have methods to change color.

Regards

Comment: No I did not try that but I just wanted to change the color and not change the component.Can you help me to access to that ?

Comment: could you put your code here. I want to see the problem ?

Comment: ok Mr Guilherme,
I already add the code
 ,thank you for your help :)

Comment: Hi, miss Aicha,

I tried to correct the problem. To do it I've used some ways of the another answer ... here ... the Navigaion Page.

I notice that you can't use the barTextColor in Masterdetail page  but you can use it in navigation page before you create the line of your application.

So try to use it in your application XAML (App.zaml.cs)

 MainPage = new NavigationPage (new MainView()) 
{
 BarBackgroundColor = Color.FromHex(""ED0909""), BarTextColor = Color.White
 };

I did here and work

Regards

Comment: thank you a lot Mr Guilherme , your answer worked well :D it's correct !!

Comment: Good !!
:P

Could you mark this question as solved or give your vote in this solution ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<? xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <MasterDetailPage xmlns = "http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestSpace" x:Class="MySpace.MainPage">
<MasterDetailPage.Master><local:HamburgerPage x:Name="hamburgerPage" />
</MasterDetailPage.Master>
<MasterDetailPage.Detail>
<NavigationPage BarBackgroundColor = "#ed0909" BarTextColor="White">
<x:Arguments> 
<local:HomePage /> 
</x:Arguments> 
</NavigationPage>
</MasterDetailPage.Detail>
</MasterDetailPage>
```

Check with this code.